# Is there a "canonical work" for radio amateurism?

Tags: radio, electromagnetism

My friends and family have been radio amateurs and I'm not very familiar with radio technology. I know basic mathematical physics but I only know the X25 and the As400 (or what's its name) by name and nothing more. as a computer engineer I have found that there are "canonical works" that are referred to e.g. for computer engineering, for computer science, for hobbyist electronics, so now I wonder if you can tell me about whether there is a good recommendation how to not get started in practice with radio amateurism, but rather how to gain a knowledge about how it works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup. That would be the still amazingly low priced at $49, even after being in publication for 90 years, [Radio Amateur's Handbook](http://www.arrl.org/shop/ARRL-Handbook-2013-Softcover-Edition). This book was my electronics & radio bible all through high school. Most of the theory I learned before studying EE in university came from it.. If you don't want to buy one, most libraries have back issues.

Comment: One thing I'd like to mention about the Handbook is that different editions have different focus. Some editions have more material about making a radio yourself, some have lots of information about tube radios, so depending on your interests, it may be worthwhile to look up older editions in libraries

Answer (score 2):

If you can find a copy at a reasonable price, [Solid State Design for the Radio Amateur](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0872592014) is a must-have.  However, every ham who owns a copy knows what it is worth, and just about every copy offered for sale has a 3-digit pricetag attached.